# Issue finding a JUnit test for this program

Tags: java, junit

I'm currently working on a program called JPhotoFrame and need to write a JUnit test for it. The issue is I'm not entirely sure how to write the test. Here's my code:

```
package PhotoFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JPhotoFrame extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
    JCheckBox locBox = new JCheckBox("On location", false);
    JCheckBox studioBox = new JCheckBox("In studio", false);
    JCheckBox oneBox = new JCheckBox("One human subject ", false);
    JCheckBox moreBox = new JCheckBox("Two or more human subjects ", false);
    JCheckBox petBox = new JCheckBox("Pet subject ", false);
    JLabel mainLabel = new JLabel("Paula's Portaits");
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 30);
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Portrait fee");
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Select options");
    JTextField totPrice = new JTextField(10);
    String output;
    final double LOC_PRICE = 90.00;
    double ONE_HUMAN_SUBJECT_PRICE = 40.00, MORE_HUMAN_SUBJECTS_PRICE = 75.00;
    double PET_SUBJECT_PRICE = 95.00;
    double locPrice = 0.00;
    double subPrice = 0.0;

    public JPhotoFrame() {
        setTitle("PhotoFrame");
        setLayout(flow);
        add(mainLabel);
        add(label1);
        ButtonGroup gp = new ButtonGroup();
        gp.add(locBox);
        gp.add(studioBox);
        locBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(locBox);
        studioBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(studioBox);
        oneBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(oneBox);
        moreBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(moreBox);
        petBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(petBox);
        add(label2);
        add(totPrice);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent check) {
        subPrice = 0;
        if (studioBox.isSelected()) {
            subPrice = subPrice + 40.00;
        } else if (locBox.isSelected()) {
            subPrice = subPrice + LOC_PRICE;
        }
        if (oneBox.isSelected()) {
            subPrice = subPrice + ONE_HUMAN_SUBJECT_PRICE;
        }
        if (moreBox.isSelected()) {
            subPrice = subPrice + MORE_HUMAN_SUBJECTS_PRICE;
        }
        if (petBox.isSelected()) {
            subPrice = subPrice + PET_SUBJECT_PRICE;
        }
        totPrice.setText(String.format("%.2f", subPrice));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPhotoFrame frame = new JPhotoFrame();
        frame.setSize(320, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

How would I test this? I'm not sure which Assert statement to use.

Comment: You should consider reading up on Model-View-Control which would help you writing testable code.

Comment: At first you should seperate the gui code and the code for the price buildung. Then you can write junit tests  for all different cases of the peice building.